# How do i reset auto increment id in sqlite ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I created a sqlite database table with 3 rows in iOS. Then I deleted the 2nd row from the table. Now the auto increment id has 1 and 3.

How do I reset the id?

Comment: Why do you want to reset it? Perfectly normal behaviour for an auto increment.

Comment: i want delete row by index path in table view.

Comment: You can just update the row with ID = 3 to have the value you want (eg. 2)

Answer (score 0):

As for as i think you need to delete the table and create a new table again to rest the auto increment column.

You can update the existing id.